# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width_pert' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width_pert' of undefined"` on line

`var getWidth = (player_value['width_pert']*window.innerWidth)/100;`

in the following code.

```
function zoomIn() {
    player_value['width_pert'] = player_value['width_pert'] + 20;
    if(player_value['zindex'] == '1'){              
        //console.log(player_value['width_pert'] + ' ssss');
        $('.viewPresentation').css({
            'width' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%',
            'height' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%'
        });
    } else {
        $('.viewPDF').css({ 
            'width' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%',
            'padding-top' : parseInt(player_value['width_pert']*parseFloat(player_value['ratio'])) + '%'
        });             
        player_value['padding_top_pert'] = parseInt(player_value['width_pert']*parseFloat(player_value['ratio']));
        getPageDim();
    }
}

function zoomOut() {
    //console.log(player_value['width_pert'] + ' ssss 777');
    if(player_value['width_pert'] > 40) {
        player_value['width_pert'] = player_value['width_pert'] - 20;
        if(player_value['zindex'] == '1'){              
            $('.viewPresentation').css({
                'width' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%',
                'height' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%'
            });
        } else {
            $('.viewPDF').css({
                'width' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%',
                'padding-top' : parseInt(player_value['width_pert']*parseFloat(player_value['ratio'])) + '%'
            });
            player_value['padding_top_pert'] = parseInt(player_value['width_pert']*parseFloat(player_value['ratio']));
            getPageDim();
        }
    }
}

function fitwidth(scale) {
    if(player_value['zindex'] == '0'){
        playerState = 'normal';
        player_value['width_pert'] = scale;
        $('.viewPDF').css({
            'width' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%',
            'padding-top' : parseInt(player_value['width_pert']*parseFloat(player_value['ratio'])) + '%'
        });
        player_value['padding_top_pert'] = parseInt(player_value['width_pert']*parseFloat(player_value['ratio']));
        getPageDim();
        clearTimeout(tmrSlideActions);
        tmrSlideActions = setTimeout(positionSlide, 500);
    }
}

function fitpage() {    
    if(player_value['zindex'] == '0'){  
        playerState = 'fitpage';    
        var heightFit = window.innerHeight;
        if(player_value['fixed'] == '1'){
            heightFit = heightFit - parseInt($('#nav').css('height') + 5) ;
        }
        var widthTemp = parseInt(heightFit/player_value['ratio']);
        if(widthTemp > window.innerWidth){
            player_value['width_pert'] = 100;
        } else {
            player_value['width_pert'] = (widthTemp/window.innerWidth)*100; 
        }           
        player_value['padding_top_pert'] = (heightFit / window.innerWidth)*100;
        $('.viewPDF').css({
            'width' : player_value['width_pert'] + '%',
            'padding-top' : player_value['padding_top_pert'] + '%'
        }); 
function getPageDim(){      
    var getWidth = (player_value['width_pert']*window.innerWidth)/100;
    pageHeight = parseFloat(player_value['padding_top_pert']*window.innerWidth/100) + 0.5;                                  
}
```

Don't know why getting this error.Places where `width_pert` is used is shown in the code. `width_pert` is used for getting the page width. Also one more thing like to mention that the changes done in the script file are not reflecting on the `localhost`

Comment: where have you defined `player_value ` ? Seems like you have not defined it.

Comment: I have declared  player_value as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

there's no `player_value` in the `function getPageDim() {}`. maybe you can pass it as a parameter or declare it in the upper scope.

even if declared as global, `player_value`needs to be initialised, for example:

```
var player_value = {};

function zoomIn() { ... }
function zoomOut() { ... }
...
```

this error happens whenever you're trying to access a filed of an `Object` that is not yet instantiated, it's like doing `undefined['width_pert']`.

check in your code if `player_value` is correctly popolated somewhere before the `getPageDim()`is called.

in general you should always check if your parameters are consistent:

```
function anything(something) {
    if (something !== undefined) { // or just if (something)
        // do my stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I have declared player_value as a global variable